# Post a page on a subdomain

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-routing, publish, subdomain

I created a subdomain test.xxx.com, and sent the same files that are in the main domain for this test domain, but the page is not displayed. The error "This webpage is not available" is displayed.

The primary domain "xxx.com" works perfectly.

Comment: Could you please provide some more info? Where have you created the subdomain? What do you mean by "sent the same files"?

Comment: the main domain is: http://sextaigreja.com.br/
The subdomain is: http://teste.sextaigreja.com.br/
All files that have the primary domain I sent for the subdomain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you created your subdomain on the DNS server you'd also have to add an appropriate binding to your site in IIS.

Comment: How can I do this? My host site is in an Outsourced. No access to IIS.

Comment: Hmmm it looks like your site is working correctly - I checked the links you provided above - both are directing to proper sites. But the site within the subdomain fails with Security Exception.